# how to check a CSV file row-1 and row-2 is empty or not?

Tags: python, csv

i have 4 csv files in a particular folder. i want to check row-1 and row-2 of every csv file one by one. If row-1 or row-2 has blank then print 'file is empty' and print the particular file name also.

```
path = 'D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query/*.csv'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
  with open(name) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    row1 = next(reader)
    print(row1)
    row2 = next(reader)
    print(row2)
```

error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\SPate233\Downloads\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    f_row = next(reader)
StopIteration
[Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: by row1 and row2 blank you mean `,,,,,`?

Comment: means row-1 or row-2 has no record.

Comment: @amisha Can you post the code sample ,what you tried.? Please explain with samole input and output

Comment: But, If row 1 or row 2 has no record, you can't have any record. If you had a third record, that would become your first row. Could you post a sample of your CSV?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/NS dashboard/sql_query/*.csv'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    print(name)
    df = pd.read_csv(name)
    df.info(verbose=True)
```

it will print the information about your data set, if there is any null value present df.info () will highlight data.